# Qt Quick 3D custom geometry in Qt5/Qt6

Tags: render, qt5.5, qt6, qtquick3d

I'm trying to build an example project with custom geometry under Qt 5.15.2 (https://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt6-dev/qtquick3d-customgeometry-example.html)
I get all qml ui elements drawn except for the mesh. In Qt 6 all works fine and mesh is rendered.

I see on the link attached above that the example refers to Qt 6 however QQuick3DGeometry class which provides us with custom geometry exists in Qt5.
Please let me know if there's a chance to use Qt 5.15 for the purpose of rendering mesh with custom geometry and whether QQuick3DGeometry can be helpful in this case. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is to use setName() during initializing custom geometry. That's the way it works in Qt5. In Qt6 it is not necessary. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-89420